# FCC wikipedia viewer not receiving data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I'm have some serious problems getting any response data through from the mediawiki api.

I'm trying to do the freecodecamp wikipedia viewer challenge and I'm coding it here:

https://codepen.io/dceaser334/pen/zpQXOJ

All i'm trying to do so far is GET the data and print it to the console using the following request:

```
$('.search-button').on('click', function() {

  var searchInput = $('.search-input').val();

  $.getJSON('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=' + searchInput + '&format=json&callback=?', function(data) {

  console.log(data);

  });
});
```

All i'm trying to do so far is GET the data and print it to the console using the that request.

I'm getting this error in firefox:

> Loading failed for the  with source
>   “https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=jordan&format=json&callback=jQuery32105036538970753343_1518470620925&_=1518470620926”.
>   index.html:1

Nothing loads to the console and it seems like the request is blocked.

I've tried using `origin=*` which also makes no difference.

I'm a bit lost because this project has similar code for the GET request and works perfectly:

https://codepen.io/luckyguy73/pen/GqPzZO?editors=1010

```
$("#searchWiki").click(function(){
    var q = document.getElementById("searchid").value;
        $('#results').html('');                
                $.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&gsrlimit=15&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch=" + q, function(data){
                    $('#results').append('<h2>Top 15 Wiki Search Results for "' + q + '"</h2>');
                    $.each(data.query.pages, function (i) {
                        $('#results').append("<p><a href='https://en.wikipedia.org/?curid=" + data.query.pages[i].pageid + 
                            "' target='_blank'>" + data.query.pages[i].title + "</a></p>");
                    });

                });
            });
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your issue has something to do with CORS? I remember I had the same problem with it while doing this project. One way to deal with it is to use "jsonp". See my answer, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this. Maybe you will be inspired by analyzing my code?

```
( function ( $ ) {
  "use strict";

  $(document).ready(function(){

    function loadData() {
        $(".information").text(""); // Reset data before new search.
        $(function whiteFirst() {
            const query = $(".wiki_query").val();
            const myFirstWikiUrl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=";
            const mySecondWikiUrl = "&format=json&callback=wikiCallback";
            const wikiUrl = myFirstWikiUrl + query + mySecondWikiUrl;
            // MY WIKIPEDIA AJAX GOES HERE - TOP
            const wikiRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $(".small-information").html("An error occurred! Application couldn't get Wikipedia resources!");
            }, 5000); // This is 5 seconds!
            $.ajax({
                url: wikiUrl,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "GET",
            }).done(function(result) {

                const itemsOne = [];
                const itemsTwo = [];
                const itemsThree = [];

                $(result[1]).each(function(index, value) {
                    itemsOne.push(value);
                });

                $(result[2]).each(function(index, value) {
                    itemsTwo.push(value);
                });

                $(result[3]).each(function(index, value) {
                    itemsThree.push(value);
                });

                $(".information").hide();
                $(".results").hide();

                for (let i = 0; i < itemsOne.length; i++) {
                    $(".information").append("<a class='title' href=" + itemsThree[i] + " target='_blank'><div class='result'><p class='title' id='boldTitle'>" + itemsOne[i] + "</p><p>" + itemsTwo[i] + "</p></div></a>");
                }

                if (itemsOne.length === 0) {
                  $(".information").html("Nothing found!");
                }

                $(".results").show();
                $("body,html").animate({
                    'scrollTop': $(".results").offset().top
                }, 2000);    

                $(".information").fadeIn("slow");
                clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout); // This will prevent timeout from happening!

            });
            // MY WIKIPEDIA AJAX GOES HERE - BOTTOM
        });
        return false;
    };

    $(".whiteButton").click(loadData);
    $(".results").hide();

    $(function() {
      const offset = -50; // Optional offset
      $(".back").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(".cover").offset().top + offset
        }, 750);
      });
    });

  });

} ( jQuery ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I was trying to stick with using the .getJSON() method only because I haven't learnt anything about ajax yet. And others have successfully completed this project using the .getJSON() method.. doing my head in lol! Might be time to move on to ajax??

Comment: @DylanOrmston, yes I think it is time to do that! ;-) Also if you liked my answer please accept it. Thank you!